# Android port of old DOS Star Trek game

Tags: gratis, android, game

If you don't recognize this, you should probably move on to the next question. 
[image]

If you do recognize it, then you almost certainly used to play the old [DOS Star Trek game](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/star-trek-2n1).

Do you know of an Android port of it?

---

[Update] I will also accept a browser based version

Comment: Du könntest auch einfach DosBox verwenden.

Comment: Auf Android? Gibt es so was? Aha .... https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fishstix.dosbox

Comment: I need to investigate  http://www.kermitmurray.com/trek73/text-star-trek-for-android/